# Автоформатирование XML в соответствии со стилем.

Tags: xml, xmlparser

Есть xml-файл. Есть стиль для него, который используется в IntellijIDEA (по ctrl+alt+L). Так вот, как применить этот стиль не из IDEA, а из командной строки (Bash linux). Может быть существует какой-нибудь плагин для этого? Или нужно писать самому класс обработки? Тогда какие технологии использовать?

Сокращенная структура стиля:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<code_scheme name="myStyle">
  <option name="USE_SAME_INDENTS" value="true" />
  <ADDITIONAL_INDENT_OPTIONS fileType="xml">
    <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
    <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="8" />
    <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="4" />
    <option name="USE_TAB_CHARACTER" value="false" />
    <option name="SMART_TABS" value="false" />
    <option name="LABEL_INDENT_SIZE" value="0" />
    <option name="LABEL_INDENT_ABSOLUTE" value="false" />
    <option name="USE_RELATIVE_INDENTS" value="false" />
  </ADDITIONAL_INDENT_OPTIONS>
</code_scheme>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая стандартная технология XSLT - трансформация/форматирование XML документов с использованием XSL стилей.

Но это жесть... Составление XSL стилей это похоже на плавание по реке отравленной ядохимикатами.

Как-то занимался в свое время трансформацией XML документов на HTML/XHTML/WML в зависимости от типа клиента - до сих пор вспоминаю с дрожью.

Код будет примерно такой (обычно на базе XSLT движка [Xalan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xalan) ):

```
public class MySimpleTransform {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {  
      TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("myTransform.xslt"));
      transformer.transform(new StreamSource("input.xml"), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("output.xml")));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
          t.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

В общем вам надо написать myTransform.xslt. Примерный туториал [здесь](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/index.html?page=1)

Comment: У меня так и получается. На входе XML -> применяю к ней стиль XSL -> во время обработки сбивается форматирование -> отредактированная XML -> применяем к ней форматирование.
И вот нужно как-то придумать последний этап.

Comment: Не - неправильно: надо сразу форматировать через XSL, а не пытаться после трансформации форматировать еще раз

Comment: Это, конечно вопрос не сюда, но вы случайно не знаете, почему не работает такой параметр в xsl 2.0:

<xsl:param name="width" select="160"/>

На выходе все равно получаются строки максимум в 80 символов.
Я задал такой вопрос уже тут: http://hashcode.ru/questions/176258/xslt-2-0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-width

Answer (score -2):

Если я всё правильно понял, то вряд ли ты найдешь уже готовое решение, придется всё делать ручками. Для парсинга я б советовал юзать [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html) или [SAX](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/).

Вот пример парсинга на dom4j:

```
 public void bar(Document document) {
        List list = document.selectNodes( "//foo/bar" );

        Node node = document.selectSingleNode( "//foo/bar/author" );

        String name = node.valueOf( "@name" );
 }
```

Comment: А может быть вы знаете, в каком классе можно указать размер отступа, табуляцию и прочие свойства форматирования?